# Haskell foldr function in instance Foldable

Tags: haskell, fold

```
data Tree a = Empty | Tree a (Tree a) (Tree a)
deriving (Show, Eq, Read)
```

I have this data Tree in my programm and i need a foldr funtion in `instance Foldable Tree where`.  The Function should go first through pivot element then smaller tree and then bigger tree.

But i couldn't figure out how to go first with pivot element. I mean, how can i find the pivot Element in a tree in Haskell?

I used quicksort before, which use a pivot element to sort a list.(thats actually what i understood from quicksort) But i don't know how to search(or find) the pivot in a list or in a tree.

here is a example:

```
foldr (++) [] (Tree "m" (Tree "b" (Tree "a" Empty Empty) (Tree "g" Empty Empty)) (Tree "z" Empty Empty))
```

and the output should seem like this

`"mbagz"`

```
instance Foldable Tree
 where
    foldr _ b Empty = b
    foldr op b (Tree val left right) = foldr op (foldr op (op val b) left) right
```

I did already implement a foldr function but it works not exactly what i want.

Comment: If you need to compare tree elements when folding, then it cannot be a Foldable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you want to process the elements. This can be done in *preorder*, *inorder* or *postorder*.

For *preorder* we first process the element, and then recurse on the left and right subtree, so:

```
-- preorder
preFoldr op z = go
  where go Empty = z
        go (Tree val left right) = val `op` go left `op` go right

-- postorder
postFoldr op z = go
  where go Empty = z
        go (Tree val left right) = go left `op` go right `op` val

-- inorder
inFoldr op z = go
  where go Empty = z
        go (Tree val left right) = go left `op` val `op` go right
```

The type signatures here are however `(a -> a -> a) -> a -> Tree a -> a`, it thus can only work if the result and the item of the `Tree` have the same type. `Foldable` requires that the result can have a different type. We can however work with this with:

```
-- preorder
preFoldr op z Empty = z
preFoldr op z (Tree val left right) = val `op` preFoldr op (preFoldr op z right) left

-- postorder
postFoldr op z Empty = z
postFoldr op z (Tree val left right) = postFoldr op (postFoldr op (val `op` z) right) left

-- inorder
inFoldr op z Empty = z
inFoldr op z (Tree val left right) = inFoldr op (val `op` inFoldr op z right) left
```

For the same tree:

```
    m
   / \
  b   z
 / \
a   g
```

these then produce:

```
Prelude> preFoldr (:) [] t
["m","b","a","g","z"]
Prelude> postFoldr (:) [] t
["a","g","b","z","m"]
Prelude> inFoldr (:) [] t
["a","b","g","m","z"]
```